# watchOS 2: Name for this phone icon with a strikethrough

Tags: watchos-2

Is there an official name for this icon [image: red phone with a strike angled through it]?

In some watch apps, such as Slack, this prompt will show when the watch disconnects from the phone. I'm trying to implement this in my own watch app, but cannot find the name for this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [status icons](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205550) aren't publicly available for use in watchOS. I don't believe anyone has even written a watchOS simulator icon extractor, to determine what the system name is for that particular icon.

For now, you'd need to create your own (resized) version of that icon, and add your art to your asset catalog.

You could also [submit a feature request](https://bugreport.apple.com/) to Apple asking them to make the system icons available to developers.